# Cannot import XAVC S/AVCHD with Premiere Pro CC 2019

Tags: premiere, avchd

I am attempting to import XAVC S/AVCHD footage from Sony a6300 camera. It seems the proper way to do this is to use the Media Manager window.

The issue I am having is that it does not detect it as anything other than files, and the all other options are greyed out in Directory viewer.

- If I try to import entire PRIVATE folder, I get “File Format not supported” errors.
- If I try to import M4ROOT or M4ROOT/CLIP folders I get “The imported reported generic error” for various metadata files like XML files.

Either way it seems I am loosing metadata. Transcoding is obviously not a good option as you would end up transcoding twice.

This is XAVC S/AVCHD format and uses MP4 container so all files are within M4ROOT folder and AVCHD is empty.

How can I import this format properly with Premiere Pro CC 2019 under Windows?

Comment: Do you really care for metadata? What are you missing by importing just the media files?

Answer (score 0):

the same problem encountered here with a different sony handy cam. 
I don't know how to solve the issue but I have a way to get around it.

import both AVCHD file & MP4 file in Premiere Pro and open both in a sequence.
now use video of AVCHD file & Audio from MP4.

\\ I don't want to use video from .mp4 file because its resolution is lower than the AVCHD.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by import both, obviously there can only be one or the other format, it's a choice in the menu, you cannot have both at least I have not seen this feature on any device yet. I believe I do get audio from AVCHD it's just the errors that bug me and who knows what issues that might be causing.

Comment: @DominicM I suppose raven records a proxy video in MP4 format along with AVCHD. This is not hi-req XAVC video, but a low-res AVC, which is why he prefers AVCHD. Not sure why he thinks that audio recorded in this proxy is of higher quality than audio recorded in AVCHD file.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the files on the memory card are split up / arranged by a variety of methods to support the file system of the memory card (splitting files up so they don't break 4GB file limits, etc). If this is the case, you then need to use Sony's Catalyst Browse application to re-assemble these into standardised single video files on your editing system, rather that trying to deal with the raw files on the card.

Sony's download page is here:
https://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/catalystbrowse

The program should enable you to view the actual recordings, as opposed to the raw files. For example, I've got a card here with 36 raw video files on it, not including all the metadata files, but only 10 recorded sequences when viewed in Catalyst Browse. You should then be able to copy the recordings across to your editing machine as required, they'll be reassembled into single files per recording for you.